# Serialization : InvalidClassException scala

Tags: scala, serialization, serialversionuid

Why am I getting this error?

```
Serialization Problem 
  java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.reflect.ClassTypeManifest; 
  local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID =
```

using intellij

Comment: A bit more context wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess: you serialized (through java's built-in serialization) a class that contains a `ClassManifest` (from whom `ClassTypeManifest` is a subtype) to a file (or database), then upgraded your scala version, and are now attempting to deserialize that file, right?
Or you are sending a serialized object from one JVM process to another, and they run different versions of scala.

Well, don't do it.
The first reason is that `ClassTypeManifest` declares no explicit `serialVersionUID` field (see [What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)), which clearly indicates that any change to the class might change the serialization format. You cannot really expect any backward compatibility in `ClassTypeManifest`'s serailized streams.
In addition, in scala 2.10 `ClassManifest` is not even a class anymore: it's a mere alias to `ClassTag`  which is a significantly different class.

So really, don't expect to be able to serialize (using java's serialization) a `ClassManifest` and read it back with another version of scala.

If you really need to do use java reflection, you might try to replace your `ClassManifest` fields with `java.lang.Class` fields (which are always safe to serialize/deserialize).

Otherwise, you could look into using other serialization libraries.

Comment: why SO has scholar, student etc medals but no Psychic medal?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The solution was to use Maven lifecycle clean, and then install.